# Does "networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl" property of jvm apache httpClient.execute(httpMethod, context) effects it?

Tags: java, apache, network-programming, jvm

I have java program which is using apache http client.

```
httpClient.execute(httpMethod, context);
```

So suppose first time my server is down then execute will fail with timeout error, and i have a retry mechanism which retries the request.

So if i retry before "networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl" time, even if my server is up will i be able to get the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache is the response from DNS, not from your server. As long as DNS has responded and said that `your.server.example.com` has IP address `127.0.0.1` then it will be cached at the DNS layer, and the next time your method tries to connect it will talk to it.

The only time `networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl` comes into play is when the DNS server said `your.server.example.com` DNS name does not exist. It will defer subsequent DNS lookups until that timeout has been exceeded.

Comment: Suppose if my server is down but DNS has IP but we were not getting the reply from the server, in that case it will store current state as not active and next time, if i try within the expiry time for it, and even if my server is up is some time i will get no response right?

Comment: The cache has nothing to do with your server being up or down; its a dns cache.

Comment: So will i get start getting the response once the server is up?

Comment: The next time your retry logic occurs, the connection should be made.